# PHP and HTML (AngularJS) Date Input - Different Timezone

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress plugin in which I have a `Time Selector`. The problem is that when I send to the `PHP` which saves in `database` overrides the timezone and the time saved is different than the selected in the input.

I would like to take the data as is selected in the data input.

I use AngularJS $http object to send the post method and `PHP` as the data model.

**For example:**

```
Angular Time: 02:04 GMT+1

Data Parsed by PHP: 01:04
```

I could set my default timezone, but what will happen with an USA user who installs the plugin?

Any idea?

**EDIT:** Forgot source code

`AngularJS` Code:

```
var data_array = {
  begin_ad: $scope.begin_ad,
  end_ad: $scope.end_ad
}

$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost/models/save_ad.php',
  data: data_array
}).then(successSend, errorSending);
```

`PHP` Code:

```
$fileData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objFileData = json_decode($fileData);
$begin_ad= $objFileData -> begin_ad;
$end_ad= $objFileData -> end_ad;
$begin_ad= date('H:i:s', strtotime($begin_ad));
print $begin_ad;
```

Comment: see this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php     also look at the default timezone defined in your DB

Comment: The case is the difference between local zone at the navigator (the user of the control panel who selects a date in the input) and the zone configured in the PHP Server, how can I override one of them to match.

Comment: Can you show us the input time and output time you are getting

Comment: **Hour in my Browser:** `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:01:00 GMT+0100` | **Hour returned by PHP:** `00:01:00`